# AppBar can not get theme with material-ui V5 (Bug or Change in v5????)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I try to use material-ui v5, but I found the `AppBar` has a problem to get theme, so it doesn't show any color.

sandbox:  https://codesandbox.io/s/material-uiappbar-roquc?file=/src/App.tsx:111-403

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <AppBar color="primary" position="static">
        <Toolbar>I am AppBar! Where is my color?</Toolbar>
      </AppBar>

      <Button color="primary" variant="contained">
        color
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

In this example:

1. The `AppBar` can not get default theme color, but the `Button` can get the default theme color.
2. If you change the material-ui to `v4`, then it is all right.

Do you know, what's wrong in my code? Or there is something changed in V5?

Answer (score 1):

I found solution from github, simply wrap the code with `<StylesProvider injectFirst>`, because in material-ui v5, the Typography, Button, etc components are migrated to emotion, so we need to use the `<StylesProvider injectFirst>` to keep the CSS injection right order between emotion and JSS.

Here is the original answer from @mnajdova
https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/24109#issuecomment-750794821

The following code should work correctly

```
import { Button, AppBar, Toolbar, StylesProvider } from "@material-ui/core";
import React from "react";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <StylesProvider injectFirst>
      <div className="App">
        <AppBar color="primary" position="static">
          <Toolbar>I am AppBar! Where is my color?</Toolbar>
        </AppBar>

        <Button color="primary" variant="contained">
          color
        </Button>
      </div>
    </StylesProvider>
  );
}
```